# sum of two columns in two tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two tables and need to get sum of two columns (one in each table).

- table Games(id_tournament,id_game,email,points)  PK(id_tournament,id_game,email)
- table Results(id_tournament,email,points) PK(id_tournament,email)
- table User(id_user,email,name) PK(id_user)

example table Results:

```
1,me@hotmail.com,3 
1,you@hotmail.com,4
```

example table Games:

```
1,1,me@hotmail.com,5  
1,2,me@hotmail.com,3  
1,3,me@hotmail.com,2   
1,1,you@hotmail.com,4  
1,3,you@hotmail.com,2
```

example table User:

```
1,me@hotmail.com,John  
2,you@hotmail.com,Peter
```

My output should be:

```
John 13  
Peter 10
```

I tried to use

```
SELECT t3.name, SUM(t1.points+t2.points) as Total 
FROM user t3, games t1, results t2 
WHERE  t1.email=t2.email AND t2.email=t3.email AND  t1.id_tournament=t2.tournament 
GROUP BY t1.email 
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

but got very weird numbers.

Comment: If you want to see where your `weird numbers` are coming from, just remove the group by and the sum. (Show the column instead. You could do this for a specific user and do the math yourself.)  You will see that your joins causes the problem; which can be fixed by spencer's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the total points from the games table, and total points from results table separately, and then total them.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT v.name
      , SUM(v.points) AS points
   FROM (
          SELECT gu.name
               , SUM(g.points) AS points
            FROM games g
            JOIN user gu
              ON gu.email = g.email
           GROUP BY gu.name

           UNION ALL

          SELECT ru.name
               , SUM(r.points) AS points
            FROM results r
            JOIN user ru
              ON ru.email = r.email
           GROUP BY ru.name   
        ) v
    GROUP BY v.name
    ORDER BY v.name
```

**EDIT**

Added missing GROUP BY clauses.

If we need to return *all* values of name from the user table, even when there are no related rows in games or results...

```
 SELECT n.name
      , IFNULL(SUM(v.points),0) AS points
   FROM users n
   LEFT
   JOIN (
          SELECT gu.name
               , SUM(g.points) AS points
            FROM games g
            JOIN user gu
              ON gu.email = g.email
           GROUP BY gu.name

           UNION ALL

          SELECT ru.name
               , SUM(r.points) AS points
            FROM results r
            JOIN user ru
              ON ru.email = r.email
           GROUP BY ru.name   
        ) v
      ON v.name = n.name
    GROUP BY n.name
    ORDER BY n.name
```

Comment: this will sum points of all users from both tables, I got 2 numbers only. I need to list all users from table user and then sum points from both tables according to user's email.

Comment: @otis: I missed the GROUP BY clauses. (Databases other than MySQL would have thrown an error.) Correction applied.

Comment: sir, I thank you a lot ! (only there is an error on 3rd row from the bottom, it should be ON v.name = n.name)